# If $I(n) = \int_{0}^{\pi} \ln(1-2n\cos(x)+n^2)\text{d}x$, then what is $ \frac{I(100)}{I(10)}\cdot\frac{I(36)}{I(6)}$?

Tags: integration

> If$$I(n) = \int_{0}^{\pi} \ln(1-2n\cos(x)+n^2)\text{d}x$$ then$$\frac{I(100)}{I(10)}\cdot\frac{I(36)}{I(6)} =\text{?}$$

Comment: Please take the time to type in important parts of your question instead of including them as an image. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to people using screen readers.

Comment: How can $\;x\;$ be both the integration variable **and** the integral's upper limit?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

$\displaystyle I(n)=\int^{\pi}_{0}\ln(1-2n\cos x+n^2)dx\cdots \star$

$\displaystyle I(n)=\int^{\pi}_{0}\ln(1+2n\cos x+n^2)dx\cdots\star\star$

So $$I(n)+I(n)=\int^{\pi}_{0}\bigg[\ln(1-2n\cos x+n^2)+\ln(1+2n\cos x+n^2)\bigg]dx$$

$$2I(n)=\int^{\pi}_{0}\ln\bigg[(1+n^2)^2-4n^2\cos^2 x\bigg]dx$$

$$2I(n)=2\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\ln\bigg[(1+n^2)^2-4n^2\cos^2 x\bigg]dx$$

$$4I(n)=2\int^{\pi}_{0}\ln(1-2n^2\cos x+n^4)dx=I(n^2)$$

$$\frac{I(n^2)}{I(n)}=2$$

$$\frac{I(10^2)}{I(10)}\cdot \frac{I(6^2)}{I(6)}=2\times 2 =4$$

Comment: I think in $\star\star$, you meant $I(-n)$, how do you know $I(n) = I(-n)$ here?

Comment: $$\int^{b}_{a}f(x)dx=\int^{b}_{a}f(a+b-x)dx$$

Comment: Oh, ok. Also in the step where you multiplied them inside the ln, where you wrote $2I(n)=\int^{\pi}_{0}\ln(1-2n^2\cos x+n^4)dx=I(n^2)$, shouldn't it be cos(2x)? The answer would be different from there in that case?

Comment: I have edited my post.